# How can I determine the error android studio Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to use android studio to build some code after I have added AdMob code to it.  I followed the instructions https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

But Android Studio reports this error message: `8:53:49 PM Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 9s 340ms`.  It doesn't say what the error is.  Where can I find out what the error is?

Does anyone really use Android Studio?

Comment: i think you have to check your build.gradle file

Comment: I checked it ... I do not see any error messages of goofy color coding or weird squiggles.

Comment: or may be where you add dependency is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check error in android studio's bottom tab name "Messsages" section,it will describe your error.